Flutter FCM Notification not work after 10 min
Flutter FCM Notification not work after 10 min when app removed from background
I do another app and the notification its work when app is not opened forever , put this app after 10 min notifications not work , I think the problem from AndroidManifest.xml ( some line  for let app listen to firebase when app terminal  )
manifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <queries>
        <package android:name="xxxxxx" />
    </queries>
    <application
        android:label="xxxxx"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <service
            android:name="com.phan_tech.flutter_overlay_apps.OverlayService"
            android:exported="false" />
         <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="1" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> /> </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxx" />
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>

Main.dart
await Firebase.initializeApp();

  setupFlutterNotifications();

  await appFlyer();
  initMessaging();

Notification Funs
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'functions.dart';

// create an instance
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin rideNotification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
bool isGeneral = false;
String latestNotification = '';
int id = 0;


Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler( message) async {

  // await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  // await setupFlutterNotifications();

  showFlutterNotification(message);
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;


Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setAutoInitEnabled(true);

  NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(

    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
    announcement: false,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
  );

  print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;




  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    description:
    'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.max,
  );

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
  ///
  /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
  /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
  /// heads up notifications.
  ///

}


void showFlutterNotification( message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  isGeneral = true;
  valueNotifierHome.incrementNotifier();
}

var androidDetails = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
  '54321',
  'normal_notification',
  enableVibration: true,
  enableLights: true,
  importance: Importance.high,
  playSound: true,
  priority: Priority.high,
  visibility: NotificationVisibility.private,
);

const iosDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);

var generalNotificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iosDetails);

var androiInit = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'); //for logo
var iosInit = const DarwinInitializationSettings(
  defaultPresentAlert: true,
  defaultPresentBadge: true,
  defaultPresentSound: true,
);
var initSetting = InitializationSettings(android: androiInit, iOS: iosInit);

Future<void> initMessaging() async {
  debugPrint("initMessaging");

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetting);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
    if (message?.data != null) {
      if (message?.data['push_type'] == 'general') {
        latestNotification = message?.data['message'];
        isGeneral = true;
        valueNotifierHome.incrementNotifier();
      }
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
    (RemoteMessage message) async {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      if (notification != null) {
        if (message.data['push_type'].toString() == 'general') {
          latestNotification = message.data['message'];
          if (message.data['image'].isNotEmpty) {
            _showBigPictureNotificationURLGeneral(message.data);
          } else {
            _showGeneralNotification(message.data);
          }
        } else {
          if (requestStreamStart == null) {
            getUserDetails();
          } else {}
          _showRideNotification(message.notification);
        }
      }
    },
  );
  // FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data['push_type'].toString() == 'general') {
      latestNotification = message.data['message'];
      isGeneral = true;
      valueNotifierHome.incrementNotifier();
    }
  });


}

Future<String> _downloadAndSaveFile(String url, String fileName) async {
  final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final String filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName';
  final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  final File file = File(filePath);
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  return filePath;
}

Future<Uint8List> _getByteArrayFromUrl(String url) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.bodyBytes;
}

Future<void> _showBigPictureNotificationURLGeneral(message) async {
  latestNotification = message['message'];
  if (platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    final ByteArrayAndroidBitmap bigPicture = ByteArrayAndroidBitmap(await _getByteArrayFromUrl(message['image']));
    final BigPictureStyleInformation bigPictureStyleInformation = BigPictureStyleInformation(bigPicture);
    final AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'notification_1',
      'general image notification',
      channelDescription: 'general notification with image',
      styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation,
      enableVibration: true,
      enableLights: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: true,
      priority: Priority.high,
      visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
    );
    final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetting, onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground, onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground);

    // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(id++, message['title'], message['message'], notificationDetails);
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    if (notification != null && !kIsWeb) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  } else {
    final String bigPicturePath = await _downloadAndSaveFile(Uri.parse(message['image']).toString(), 'bigPicture.jpg');
    final DarwinNotificationDetails iosDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true, attachments: <DarwinNotificationAttachment>[
      DarwinNotificationAttachment(
        bigPicturePath,
      )
    ]);

    final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(iOS: iosDetails);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetting, onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground, onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground);
    // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(id++, message['title'], message['message'], notificationDetails);

    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    if (notification != null && !kIsWeb) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

  }
  id = id++;
}

Future<void> _showGeneralNotification(message) async {
  latestNotification = message['message'];
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'notification_1',
    'general notification',
    channelDescription: 'general notification',
    enableVibration: true,
    enableLights: true,
    importance: Importance.high,
    playSound: true,
    priority: Priority.high,
    visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
  );
  const DarwinNotificationDetails iosDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);
  const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: iosDetails);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetting, onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground, onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground);

  // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(id++, message['title'], message['message'], notificationDetails);

  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  id = id++;
}

Future<void> _showRideNotification(message) async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'notification_1',
    'ride notification',
    channelDescription: 'ride notification',
    enableVibration: true,
    enableLights: true,
    importance: Importance.max,
    playSound: true,
    priority: Priority.high,
    visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
  );
  const DarwinNotificationDetails iosDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
    presentAlert: true,
    presentBadge: true,
    presentSound: true,
  );
  const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: iosDetails);
  rideNotification.initialize(initSetting);
  await rideNotification.show(id++, message.title.toString(), message.body.toString(), notificationDetails);
  id = id++;
}


